# Reading input from a CSV to create multiple entries in a web form with Java and Selenium

Tags: java, csv, selenium, automated-tests

So I am trying to create 5 different entries into a web form using Java Selenium.

With the code below it is reading from the CSV and inputting the first entry but then just adds the same data 5 times rather than the 5 different entries in the csv and I can't figure out where I have gone wrong?

```
@Then("^I can make multiple bookings$")
public void i_can_make_multiple_bookings() throws Throwable {
    String csvFile = "hotelsDatas.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Use comma as separator
            String[] hotels = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            // Reading a line column by column
            for (int i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(hotels[i].replaceAll("\"", ""));

                driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys(hotels[0].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys(hotels[1].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                driver.findElement(By.id("totalPrice")).sendKeys(hotels[2].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                driver.findElement(By.id("depositPaid")).sendKeys(hotels[3].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                driver.findElement(By.id("checkIn")).sendKeys(hotels[4].replaceAll("\"", ""));
                driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).sendKeys(hotels[5].replaceAll("\"", ""));

                driver.findElement(By.id("createBooking")).click();
            }

            System.out.println(); // next line
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the CSVReader and don't invent a bicycle.

Comment: You can reduce all that logic to: `String[] fields = { "firstName", "lastName", "totalPrice", "depositPaid", "checkIn", "checkOut" };` ...and... `for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) driver.findElement(By.id(fields[j])).sendKeys(hotels[j].replaceAll("\"", ""));`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to follow the [M.K. Yong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/).

Comment: Mt. Polywhirl Cheers that has worked a treat. Not had a look at the M.K. Yong tutorial but as I'm trying to learn Java is it worth a look at?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just read in the CSV file first as a `List<Map>` and work from there?

After that, you can iterate over the `List` and for each `Map`, do things with each *Key*-*Value* pair.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Reader {
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> readCsv(String filename) throws IOException {
        return readCsv(filename, null, null);
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> readCsv(String filename, String[] headers) throws IOException {
        return readCsv(filename, headers, null);
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> readCsv(String filename, Type[] types) throws IOException {
        return readCsv(filename, null, types);
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> readCsv(String filename, String[] headers, Type[] types) throws IOException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        InputStream is = Reader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(reader);

        if (headers == null) {
            headers = csv.readNext();
        }

        String[] row;
        while ((row = csv.readNext()) != null) {
            Map<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                String value = row[i];

                if (types != null) {
                    if (types[i] == Double.class) {
                        entry.put(headers[i], Double.parseDouble(value));
                    } else if (types[i] == Date.class) {
                        entry.put(headers[i], new Date(Long.parseLong(value)));
                    } else if (types[i] == Boolean.class) {
                        entry.put(headers[i], new Boolean(value.toLowerCase().equals("true") || value.toLowerCase().equals("yes")));
                    } else {
                        entry.put(headers[i], value);
                    }
                }
            }

            result.add(entry);
        }

        csv.close();
        reader.close();
        is.close();

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Type[] types = { String.class, String.class, Double.class, Boolean.class, Date.class, Date.class };
            List<Map<String, Object>> records = readCsv("data.csv", types);

            System.out.println(records.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Input

```
firstName,lastName,totalPrice,depositPaid,checkIn,checkOut
Jane,Doe,200.00,yes,1512129600000,1512331200000
John,Smith,350.00,no,1512720000000,1512925200000
```

#### Output

```
{firstName=Jane, lastName=Doe, checkIn=Fri Dec 01 07:00:00 EST 2017, totalPrice=200.0, checkOut=Sun Dec 03 15:00:00 EST 2017, depositPaid=true}
{firstName=John, lastName=Smith, checkIn=Fri Dec 08 03:00:00 EST 2017, totalPrice=350.0, checkOut=Sun Dec 10 12:00:00 EST 2017, depositPaid=false}
```

---

#### Dependencies

**Gradle**

```groovy
compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1'
```

or **Maven**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

or **Direct Download**

> [>> opencsv-4.1](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.opencsv%3Aopencsv/4.1#files/com%2Fopencsv%2Fopencsv%2F4.1) ([jar](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/download_file?file_path=com%2Fopencsv%2Fopencsv%2F4.1%2Fopencsv-4.1.jar))

Comment: Thank you again. Now I have the initial test suite running I'm going to spend the afternoon refactoring all the tests. It is great to have these different ways of doing things available to me. Definitely help me with getting to grips with automation in Java

Comment: @TimEades If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted. If you found this, or any other answer, useful please also upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is causing you trouble:

```
 String[] hotels = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            // Reading a line column by column
 for (int i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
     System.out.print(hotels[i].replaceAll("\"", ""));


     driver.findElement(By.id("firstName")).sendKeys(hotels[0].replaceAll("\"", ""));
     driver.findElement(By.id("lastName")).sendKeys(hotels[1].replaceAll("\"", ""));
     driver.findElement(By.id("totalPrice")).sendKeys(hotels[2].replaceAll("\"", ""));
     driver.findElement(By.id("depositPaid")).sendKeys(hotels[3].replaceAll("\"", ""));
     driver.findElement(By.id("checkIn")).sendKeys(hotels[4].replaceAll("\"", ""));
     driver.findElement(By.id("checkOut")).sendKeys(hotels[5].replaceAll("\"", ""));

     driver.findElement(By.id("createBooking")).click();
    }
```

Lets suppose data in csv file looks like this:
`"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"`

You split data with `,` and create an instance of `String[]` with `String[] hotels = line.split(cvsSplitBy);`
This means your `hotels[]` array looks like this:

`hotels[0] = "\"one\"";` (I used String escape, because as I can see, you are replacing `"` in your code in `for` loop.

```
hotels[1] = "\"two\"";
hotels[2] = "\"three\"";
hotels[3] = "\"four\"";
hotels[4] = "\"five\"";
hotels[5] = "\"six\"";
hotels[6] = "\"seven\"";
hotels[7] = "\"eight\"";
hotels[8] = "\"nine\"";
hotels[9] = "\"ten\"";
```

Now take a look at `for` loop
`for (int i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++)`

Since the `hotels.length` gives you 10 elements, `for` loop wil be performed 10 times.

*NOW TAKE A LOOK AT EACH ITERATION:*

```
i=0
```

`System.out.println` will print `one` in the console.

driver will enter `one` in `firstName`
driver will enter `two` in `lastName`
driver will enter `three` in `totalPrice`
etc.

and it will click `createBooking` element.

*AND IT WAS ONLY THE FIRST ITERATION.*

When we go to iteration `i=1` then System will print `two`. But since `driver.findElement`'s code is in `for` loop, it will enter *THE SAME DATA IN THE SAME FIELDS AGAIN. AND IT WILL KEEP DOING THAT OVER AND OVER, UNTIL ITERATION FINISHES.*

You should get rid of `for` loop. You don't need it.